# Unable to create database tables with Generate Database from Model

Tags: entity-framework-4.1

I am using Entity Framework 4.1 and SQL Express. I have been trying to create models inside the emdx file and from that create the tables inside the a .mdf file. However, I am unable to get that work.

However, I am able to get the "Update Model from Database" to work, so there don't seem to be a problem with the connection string.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I tend to copy the generated SQL script and execute it myself using SQL (Enterprise manager 2008 in my case), gives you better feedback and more control.

Haven't really bothered setting it up so that it executes automatically, because EF sometimes makes mistakes in its scripting (e.g. trying to delete every FK twice. Once in the beginning, and then again before the containing table will be deleted).

Also, if you made a lot of changes or dropped some tables, sometimes the script isn't 100% compatible with deleting the existing database. I then just drop all FK's and tables (not just what the script tells me to) and then execute the script.

But that's just how I like to do it.